# Postgresql query to search text field for multiple strings

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that contains a text field (summary). I recently received a request to query that field for any occurrences of a long list of strings. For example, I'd like to search the "summary" field for *any* occurrences of these strings:

- apple
- banana
- carrot
- dog
- elephant
- ... x 50 more items
- zebra

Is there a simple query I can write that would return the IDs of the rows that contain any of these values?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could put them in one giant regular expression:

```
select t.*
from t
where summary similar to '%((apple)|(banana)|(carrot)|(dog)| . . .|(zebra))%';
```

An alternative, if you want more flexibility and care even less about performances:

```
with tosearch as (
      select '%apple%' as pattern union all
      . . .
      select '%zebra%'
     )
select t.*
from t join
     tosearch
     on t.summary like tosearch.pattern;
```

Comment: Thank you -- adding "similar to" to my tool belt!

Comment: It is better to use `~` operator instead of `similar to` for proper regexps, not SQL standard regexps.

Comment: is the bracket for each keyword necessary? it should work without bracket also, like `select t.*
from t
where summary similar to '%(apple|banana|carrot|dog| . . .|zebra)%';`

Comment: Found an updated answers that explains some interesting facts about similar to. Namely that it has to convert to a regex first. In my own testing I saw negligible performance changes, but could be a good resource.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions-in-postgresql

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way that comes in my mind is something like this:

```
SELECT "ID" FROM table WHERE "summary" IN ('apple', 'banana', 'carrot', 'dog', ....)
```

Try this out.

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT:** use the [similar to](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html) operator:

```
select "ID" from table where upper("summary") similar to upper('%((apple)|(banana)|...|(zebra))%')
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to find the terms *in* the column text, not that the column text *is* one of the terms.

Comment: Ah I didn't understand well, sorry

Comment: how can I add up the option for example apple and banana NOT apple or banana

Answer (score 7):

Use regex:

```
select * from mytable
where summary similar to '%(apple|banana|carrot|dog)%'
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3ab35/8) of this working